# Adding to arrays and printing arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I need help figuring out how to get the user to input a number of integers no more than 10, and then add them to an array and print them out from the array. The code I have below, when run, asks the user for the integers and then runs forever and doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // create a new scanner
    System.out.print("Enter integers between 1 and 100\n ");  
    int[] nextNumber = new int[10];
    int i = 0;
    int number = input.nextInt();

    while (i < nextNumber.length){
        i++;
        nextNumber[i] = number;
        number = input.nextInt();    
    }

    int a = 0;

    while (a  < nextNumber.length){
        a++;
        System.out.println(nextNumber[a]);   
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println(nextNumber[a]);` You should `a++` after the `System.out.println(nextNumber[a]);`

Comment: wasn't the problem, i had forgot to fix that from when i was experimenting with why it wont print. but even when the bottom line is System.out.println(nextNumber[a]); it still doesnt work

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"? Also swap a++ and println

Comment: Add some print statements between steps, inside your while blocks if you need to.  Or debug it in your IDE.  Where is it looping forever?

Comment: when you enter in the integers, it doesn't print anything and just continues to run

Comment: Do you even know if it's making it to the last while block?  And please post your latest code.

Comment: turns out it was a problem with the ide... i had to restart it for it to work. But maybe you could help with one other problem i have? If the user doesn't enter 10 integers what will happen?

Comment: Assuming you've fixed your incrementing issues, I don't think you'll ever get out of the first while block. (i will never be > your array size.

Comment: but wouldn't nextNumber.length be the number of integers stored inside of it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39700/discussion-between-nfoggia-and-andrew)

Comment: No, nextNumber.length will be 10, because that's what you initialized it as, no matter how many elements are populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you increment your index too fast. You should increment your index variables at the *end* of your loops, not the *beginning*.

I would suggest you use for loops instead since they are designed for that:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // create a new scanner
System.out.print("Enter integers between 1 and 100\n ");

int[] nextNumber = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < nextNumber.length; i++){
    nextNumber[i] = input.nextInt();
}

for (int a = 0; a  < nextNumber.length; a++){
    System.out.println(nextNumber[1]);
}
```

Also, although I did not change it in the code, it seems like your last line should be:

```
System.out.println(nextNumber[a]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Increment the array index after the values have been assigned to the arrays

```
while (i < nextNumber.length) {
    number = input.nextInt();
    nextNumber[i] = number;
    i++;
}
```

The same applys to the second loop

```
while (a < nextNumber.length) {
    System.out.println(nextNumber[a]);
    a++;
}
```

Comment: still has the same problem. my program continues to run with nothing outputting to the screen

Comment: Actually the original problem was an `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` but worked just fine there, silly question: are you running the current version, clean/rebuild etc?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**

Change

```
int i = 0;
int number = input.nextInt();
while (i < nextNumber.length){
i++;  //here is one problem. you not assigning the value to nextNumber[0].
nextNumber[i] = number;
number = input.nextInt();

}
```

to

```
int i = 0;
while (i < nextNumber.length){
   number = input.nextInt();
   nextNumber[i] = number;
   i++;  
}
```

**Problem 2**

change

```
int a = 0;
while (a  < nextNumber.length){
    a++;  //here is one problem ..You never get  nextNumber[0] value
System.out.println(nextNumber[a]);

}
```

to

```
int a = 0;
while (a  < nextNumber.length){
     System.out.println(nextNumber[a]);
    a++;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i noticed that too, but isn't the problem. Still doesnt run :/

Comment: still has the same problem. my program continues to run with nothing outputting to the screen

Comment: @nfoggia you need to give 10 inputs one by one. type one number then press Enter key. do it 10 times

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this as follows. Better use for loop since you know the maximum number of iterations.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // create a new scanner
System.out.print("Enter integers between 1 and 100\n ");  
int[] nextNumber = new int[10];

int i = 0;
while (i < nextNumber.length)   nextNumber[i++] =  input.nextInt();


int a = 0;
while (a  < nextNumber.length)  System.out.println(nextNumber[a++]);
```

Comment: Make it clear & correct first, long before you make it super-concise.  I like the loop-body on a separate line;  and definitely prefer advancement/increment to have _it's own_ line for clarity. The OP here is a beginner, suggesting the most-terse C-style when he can't even place his increments correctly is not guiding him down the path to clear & simple correct code.

Comment: What you are saying is true Thomas. It can be simplify by separating them for line by line. But it does the same job. I wanted to illustrate the optimal code for his example.